# Não encontro os erros

Tags: c++

Alguem pode me ajudar, este programa esta dando diversos erros, mas eu não encontro nenhum. Desde já agradeço.

Erros:

1. [Error] cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' for argument '3' to 'int leitura(int, int, int**)'
2. [Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
3. [Error] initializing argument 3 of 'int impressao(int, int, int*)' [-fpermissive]
4. [Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
5. [Error] initializing argument 4 of 'int somatorio(int, int, int*, int*)' [-fpermissive]
6. [Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
7. [Error] initializing argument 3 of 'int maior(int, int, int*, int*)' [-fpermissive]
8. [Error] expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
9. [Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <sstream>
   #include <cmath>
   using namespace std;
   int leitura(int i, int q_numeros, int *vetor[1000]);
   int impressao(int i, int q_numeros, int vetor[1000]);
   int somatorio(int i, int q_numeros, int *soma, int vetor[1000]);
   int maior(int i, int q_numeros, int vetor[1000], int *max);
   int fimpar(int *impar, int i, int q_numeros, int vetor[1000]);
   int main(){
      int q_numeros, vetor[1000], i, max, soma, impar;
      cout<<"Programa que apartir dos numeros inseridos diz quem são eles, o seu somatorio, qual é o maior e quantos impares foram digitados.";
       cout <<"\nDigite quantidade de numeros a ser inseridos no programa:";
       cin >> q_numeros;
       leitura(i, q_numeros, &vetor[1000]);
       impressao(i, q_numeros, vetor[1000]);
       somatorio( i, q_numeros, &soma,vetor[1000]);
       cout<<"\nSomatorio dos numeros digitados é:"<<soma<<endl;
       maior( i,  q_numeros, vetor[1000], &max);
       cout<<"\nMaior numero é: "<< max<<endl;
       int fimpar (&impar, i, q_numeros, vetor[1000]);
       cout<<"n\A quantidade de numeros impares é: "<< impar<<endl;
       return 0;
   }   
   int leitura(int i, int q_numeros, int *vetor[1000]){
       cout<<"digite os numeros";
       for(i=0; i<q_numeros;i++){
       cin >> *vetor[i];
   }
   return 0;
   }

   int impressao(int i, int q_numeros, int vetor[1000]){
       cout << "Numeros digitados foram:\n";
       for(i=0; i<q_numeros;i++)
       {
       cout << vetor[i]<<"\n"<< endl;
       }
   return 0;
   }
   int somatorio(int i, int q_numeros, int *soma, int vetor[1000]){
       for(i=0; i<q_numeros;i++){
           *soma=*soma+vetor[i];
       }
   return 0;
   }

   int maior(int i, int q_numeros, int vetor[1000], int *max){
       for(i=0; i<q_numeros;i++) {
       if (max<vetor[i]) {
           *max=vetor[i];
       }
       else{
       }
   }
   return 0;
   }
   int fimpar (int *impar, int i, int q_numeros, int vetor[1000]) {

       for(i=0; i<q_numeros;i++){
           if ((vetor[i] % 2) == 0){
           }
           else
           {
               *impar++;
        }
   }
   return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Pode enumerar quais erros estão aparecendo?

Comment: Sempre que for fazer uma pergunta seja o mais específico possível. Neste caso faltou informar que erros ocorrem. Recomende que visite estes links: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e principalmente http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask-beta

Comment: Pra que tantos votos negativos tão rápido? O cara é novo, a dica foi dada nos comentários. Acho que poderiam esperar um pouco, até desanima o rapaz a complementar a pergunta.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo eu não dei -1, mas creio q alguns deles foram porque a questão original (antes da minha edição) estava desformatada.

Comment: Brigado pela ajuda. Vou elaborar melhor as próximas perguntas.

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo No meu modo de ver esses votos negativos (se dados de forma imediata) podem afastar usuários novos que ainda não aprenderam e também fazer com que usuários experientes não cliquem na pergunta para respondê-la por achar que ela realmente não serve, mesmo que já tenha sido editada e complementada da forma correta.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Concordo, até porque tem gente que negativa e não retira o voto, quando a questão ficou boa.

Answer (score 1):

Seguinte, na sua declaração:

```
int leitura(int i, int q_numeros, int *vetor[1000]);
```

Repare que você está pedindo um ponteiro de array. O identificador de um array já é um ponteiro (pro primeiro endereço do array), sendo assim neste pode até ser considerado que você quer um ponteiro de ponteiro.

No seu caso acho que o melhor seria fazer assim:

```
int leitura(int i, int q_numeros, int vetor[1000]);
```

e

```
leitura(i, q_numeros, vetor);
```

Nesta linha acima, eu passei apenas o nome pois como citei o nome é um array.

Os demais erros seguem a mesma lógica.

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo.

Comment: só uma correção: `int *vetor[1000]` não declara um _ponteiro de array_, mas um **array de ponteiros**... que definitivamente não era o que ele queria. Por causa da precedência de operadores, um ponteiro de array seria `int (*vetor)[1000]`. E @HenriqueMelo, se a resposta resolveu seu problema, marque como resposta certa (debaixo do número dos votos da resposta, tem um "tique" verde delineado na qual você clica para marcar aquela resposta)